# how to convert date UTC to local and Local to UTC?

Tags: ios, swift3, timezone, utc

I want to convert date from local to UTC and UTC to Local.

For eg. Apr 1, 2015, 12:00 PM is UTC then

Apr 1, 2015, 5:30 PM is Local for me but I am getting reverse of it

```
let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"[![enter image description here][1]][1]
dateFormatter2.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
let date2 = dateFormatter2.date(from: "2015-04-01T12:00:00")


dateFormatter2.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone
let date3 = dateFormatter2.date(from: "2015-04-01T12:00:00")
```

I am getting Apr 1, 2015, 5:30 PM as UTC and
Apr 1, 2015, 12:00 PM as Local

[image]

Comment: Don't use Foundation types in Swift when they have native Swift alternatives. Use `TimeZone` instead of `NSTimeZone`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally this worked for me

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2015-04-01 12:00:00")
        print("UTC time",date!)

        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)

        print("Local time",timeStamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The local time zone is always based on the default timzone that has been set for your app.

From the Apple documentation

> Returns an object that forwards all messages to the default time zone for the current application.

Try using `NSTimeZone.system` instead. This will always make sure that it will provide the timezone that has been set by the user in the iOS Settings.

Comment: Not Working still getting same

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter2.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
dateFormatter2.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let date2 = dateFormatter2.date(from: "2015-04-01T12:00:00")


dateFormatter2.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
let date3 = dateFormatter2.date(from: "2015-04-01T12:00:00")
```

Comment: local time :  "Apr 1, 2015, 12:00 PM"
UTC time  "Apr 1, 2015, 5:30 PM" it should be revere

Comment: UTC time should be "Apr 1, 2015, 6:30 AM" if local Time is 12:00 PM

Comment: @JayprakashSingh What is the timezone set in your device ?

Comment: i am using simulator and display system time which is UTC +5:30

Comment: I got date2 as :(2015-04-01 06:30:00 +0000) and date3 as (2015-04-01 12:00:00 +0000)

Comment: are you using simulator or physical device ? i am using simulator, do i need to set any thing setting ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154442/discussion-between-jayprakash-singh-and-sneha).

Comment: @JayprakashSingh Sneha code working in simulator also i checked.

Comment: @JayprakashSingh I'm using simulator. You don't have to set anything. The simulator uses the system settings, so it will take local as the timezone of the system.

Comment: now its code working date to as :(2015-04-01 06:30:00 +0000)  but how it knows date is UTC and convert to local